# SIM800L AT+CPIN="xxxx" return error

Tags: arduino, sim-card

When checking the status (AT+CPIN?) of my chip I get the following return:
*"SIM PIN required, SIM PUK code required."*

And when I try to activate the PIN I get the following error:
*AT+CPIN="xxxx"

Error*

How can I find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got reply "SIM PIN required, SIM PUK code required."
You need to enter both PUK and PIN codes.

> AT+CPIN="xxxxxxxx","yyyy"

where:

- xxxxxxxx - PUK code
- yyyy - PIN code

Google knows everything: 
[[Hilo] How to manage the PIN code of SIM card? | HL Series FAQ ...](https://forum.sierrawireless.com/viewtopic.php?f=162&t=7112)